# Is Mei Misaki dead?

Tags: another

I'm on episode 5. So they avoid her to not run into bad luck and stuff... but that means they see her (even though Misaki said they couldn't) so does that mean she's alive? Or is she dead?

Comment: everything gets explained in the last episode

Comment: Better watch it 'til the end. It'll be boring knowing everything while watching. But since an answer was already posted, meh. Hope you'll enjoy watching with that BIG SPOILER.

Comment: BIG SPOILER is a damn understatement... the whole story revolves around this

Answer (score 6):

Can't post this as a comment, since spoilers. Big spoilers.

> No, she is not dead. She's labelled as the classroom's "one that doesn't exist" student in order to make up for the extra, but she isn't the one that's dead. She happens to have the ability to see the one that's dead, and tries to tell Kouichi who it is before being interrupted.

Comment: really? I didn't get that she could see at all, must have missed it.

Answer (score -2):

> Death is not kind. It's dark, black as far as you can see, and you're all alone. 
>   - Mei Misaki

Her status is alive, so she isn't dead, but she was labeled by her classmates as "The one who does not exist". So what I'm saying is, she is alive

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that particular quote is relevant to determining if she's alive or not?